# SVN relocation - Inner folders still have older reposiory location

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I have set up new repository and relocated all users to new location. But some users still have inner folders pointing to old repository.

**So when they commit, changes propagate to old repository** and their working copy has no clue about it.

***Is there any way to check whether a particular working copy points to specific repository or not?***

I am using subversion and apache server to host it. TortoiseSVN on client side.

Thanks

Comment: Tell us your Subversion version. I know simple solution for 1.7. But for <1.7 the solution should be simple too, but a bit is slightly different (working copy format has changed).

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using Subversion 1.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every path theoretically may have own URL.

You may run:
    $ svn info --depth infinity | grep 'Repository Root'
on the working copy to see all repository roots.

This should work for both 1.6 and 1.7

At low level for SVN 1.7 you may look into .svn/wc.db table:

```
$ sqlite3 wc.db 
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from REPOSITORY;
1|file:///tmp/test|0c483d57-60fd-477d-b0c6-ccd144a87a70
```

And all repos_id field values of NODES table have value 1.

After relocate to svn://localhost, I have:

```
sqlite> select * from REPOSITORY;
1|file:///tmp/test|0c483d57-60fd-477d-b0c6-ccd144a87a70
2|svn://localhost|0c483d57-60fd-477d-b0c6-ccd144a87a70
```

And all repos_id field values of NODES table are changed to 2 now.